# Why isn't this variable expanded with eval?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a question about the following makefile. I use GNU Make v4.1.

```
define code
    foo:=hello
    bar:=${foo}
endef

$(eval ${code})
default:
    #${foo}
    #${bar}
```

`${foo}` echoes `hello`, but `${bar}` echoes nothing. Why is this happening?
I expected `${bar}` to echo `hello` too, because I think this is equivalent to the following makefile:

```
foo:=hello
bar:=${foo}
default:
    #${foo}
    #${bar}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `$(info ${code})` to see what's going on.

`${foo}` was expanded when the definition of `code` was build, so `code` contains

```
    foo:=hello
    bar:=${foo}
```

If you want `${foo}` to be expanded when you run `$(eval ${code})`, which is what makes `eval` useful, then you need to make the value of `code` contain a dollar sign.

```
define code
    foo:=hello
    bar:=$${foo}
endef
```

In this case, you could achieve the same result by making `bar` a late-expansion definiton:

```
bar=${foo}
foo:=hello
default:
    #${foo}
    #${bar}
```

`eval` is useful in more complex cases, especially when string being eval'ed is built dynamically.

Comment: Thank you so much.I understood perfectly and also appreciate you to correct my grammatical mistakes in English.I will apply myself.

Answer (score 1):

I'm original poster.I found another function 'value' which return value without expansion.

```
define code
    foo:=hello
    bar:=${foo}
endef

$(eval $(value code))
default:
    #${foo}
    #${bar}
```

This also works too.

Comment: `$(value...)` is really helpful in keeping syntax sane when using `$(eval...)`